# YouTube movies are playing too fast with chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I've got movies playing in fast forward in YouTube HTML 5 mode if I play it in Google Chrome. If I open it with Firefox, it plays well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you're using Chrome from the `dev` or `unstable` channels, you probably have a bad Flash plugin enabled (this affects HTML5 audio as well for some obscure reason).

To fix it, go to `chrome://plugins` and disable all the flash plugins. Then click <kbd>+</kbd>`Details` to show the individual versions of Flash, enable them one at a time until the problem goes away.

This is the configuration that worked for me:

[image: flash plugin configuration in chrome]

If you none of the versions you have work, you may need to install the `adobe-flashplugin` package:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Sadly if you only have the NPAPI version enabled most websites seem to think you don't have flash at all!

Comment: Yes, disabling of Shockwave Flash 11.3 r31 helped me. The only difference is that I'm using OpenSUSE 12.1 distro.

Answer (score 41):

**Please note:**  sometimes if the problem still persists then this may be related to pulseaudio, in such case you can use

```
killall pulseaudio
```

pulseaudio would start automatically again

And restart the browser and it will work.

If this only works temporarily, you can try [replacing pulse audio with the alsa module](http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-How-to-Pulseaudio-and-Alsa) for good.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Strange thing was that using Jacob's solution gave me either a really fast youtube or a really stuttery and slow one.

Comment: Same as ubershmekel here. Selecting a specific flash plugin made it either very slow or even faster. Leaving the plugins as they were and just killing and starting pulseaudio did the trick. Note: `sudo service pulseaudio restart` did NOT help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly restart it. It should start automatically as needed when not running..

Comment: The problem just came back after a long hiatus. Any idea for a permanent fix?

Comment: just killing worked for me. It seems it restarts itself

Answer (score 17):

I found some solutions:

- Reset you're sound settings, (apparantly if you use hdmi for audio and video there is nothing slowing the playback down) so what you have to do is try changing audio playback device :)
- One user found that "setting the specific speaker layout fixed my problem (from nothing to 5.1, as that is what I have)."

Comment: Here I am a year and a half later to find out that HDMI audio does screw up the playback. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Audio playback configuration changed somehow and was indeed the reason video playback was going too fast. Something you wouldn't easily guess but thanks for this answer because it solved my problem! In my case I changed it back to line-out and playback was normal again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For me it was related to an install of Totem video player which installed a vlc multimedia plugin for chrome:

VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Totem 3.0.1)

Disabling this plugin made it work!