# Flash videos choppy after computer has been ON for a day or so

Tags: 11.10, video, flash

I find that flash videos are extremely choppy (in firefox) or are really sped up as if on fast forward (on chrome) when my Ubuntu 11.10 has been ON for more than a day or so. Usually restarting the computer helps.

My flash version is: 11,2,202,238
Is there any process that I can turn off and then turn on instead of rebooting my computer?

I tried this to no avail: [YouTube movies are playing too fast with chrome](https://askubuntu.com/q/141692/41821)

Comment: One solution is provided here:
http://askubuntu.com/q/158948/41821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with pulseaudio.

`killall pulseaudio` and then restarting it made the problem disappear.