# Video plays back too quickly, sound problem - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: sound, youtube, playback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [YouTube movies are playing too fast with chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141692/youtube-movies-are-playing-too-fast-with-chrome)

Firstly I have problem with my sound on my computer. When I listen to music sometimes sound lagging for two or three seconds and for the rest of song it plays OK. 
Secondly I can't watch youtube or Vimeo videos because it plays very fast. 
For example 3 minutes video can be played at 20 secounds.
I tried to use other chrome Version or firefox - that don't fix my problem.

My Ubuntu Version: 12.04 LTS
Music player: Audacious
Web browser: Google Chrome or Firefox.
MB: asrock p67 pro3
Speakers: Genius Sw-Hf 5.1 6000
Drivers: Installed with ubuntu, graphics driver from additional drivers (in system).
Graphics card: Geforce GT220
PSU: Chieftec gpa-500s
CPU: Intel core i5 2500k
HDD: OCZ agility 3
Sound Card: Realtek ALC892

I'm so sorry for my english (I am from Poland).
Thank you in advance.

Konrad

Answer (score 0):

Probably that you need the `adobe-flashplugin` package:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

If it doesn't help, see other methods [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141692/youtube-movies-are-playing-too-fast-with-chrome).

Comment: I have a Shockwave Flash 11.3 r31. I have tried all of these thing. It not help for me.