# Sudden flash malfunctions

Tags: firefox, internet, google-chrome, flash, netflix

I have begun having some odd problems playing Netflix, Amazon VOD, Hulu, Youtube and other flash videos.  The videos play slightly faster than they should (seems to be 50% faster) and they have no sound.  This happens in Chrome and Netflix-Desktop (using a specialized wine and firefox combo), http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/

However, video works perfectly fine under Firefox (except for netflix-desktop, since it is a program installed on the computer under wine).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the netflix-desktop issue: It is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+bug/1090348) with pulseaudio and netflix-desktop. You should restart the pulseaudio server, by

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Restarting the pulseaudio server may even solve your flash problems with Chrome, so try this first. Or you can find in that bug report a [link](http://hongouru.blogspot.hu/2013/06/solved-netflix-desktop-has-choppy-video.html) to a website with another solution.

Chrome uses it's internal flash plugin, whereas Firefox uses the system-wide plugin. If Chrome behaves badly, but firefox not, then most likely it is a problem with the internal plugin. Please [look here](https://askubuntu.com/q/141692/221281) for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone visiting this question in the future, this is what I did.

First off, I found out that Chrome had a version of Flash that didn't work well with pulseaudio and had issues over-riding HTML 5.  My solution was to use Chromium instead.  I was already undecided on which I liked better, and switching fixed the problem like a charm.  Another solution was to install ALSA, but I didn't want to mess around with my audio system that was working fine other than Chrome.

Then, there was the problem of netflix-desktop.  My solution was to use pipelight, which is a browser plugin that provides Silverlight functionality.  The guide is here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Be sure to follow the entire guide.  At the bottom is a step about spoofing netflix so it appears your running Firefox under Windows.  Otherwise, Netflix will flag you as using an unsupported browser.